<AntiforgeryToken /> tag creates nothing on page (blazor server)
I have this code in an interactiveserver component:
<form action="Account/Logout" method="post">
     <AntiforgeryToken />
     <input type="hidden" name="ReturnUrl" value="@currentUrl">
     <button type="submit" class="nav-link border-0 text-white"
             @onclick="@Logout">
         <LocalText Key="Logout"></LocalText>
     </button>
 </form>

I want to send this form to a microsoft default identity core endpoint:
 accountGroup.MapPost("/Logout", async (
     ClaimsPrincipal user,
     SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager,
     [FromForm] string returnUrl) =>
 {
     await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
     return TypedResults.LocalRedirect($"~/{returnUrl}");
 });

I configured antiforgery like this:
  var app = builder.Build();
   ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseAntiforgery();
    
    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
    
    app.MapAdditionalIdentityEndpoints();
    
    
    app.Run();

But when I want to logout this error is raised:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AntiforgeryValidationException: The required antiforgery request token
was not provided in either form field "__RequestVerificationToken" or
header value "RequestVerificationToken".
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext
httpContext)
BadHttpRequestException: Invalid anti-forgery token found when reading
parameter "string returnUrl" from the request body as form.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory+Log.InvalidAntiforgeryToken(HttpContext
httpContext, string parameterTypeName, string parameterName, Exception
exception, bool shouldThrow)
Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing AntiforgeryValidationException:
The required antiforgery request token was not provided in either form
field "__RequestVerificationToken" or header value
"RequestVerificationToken".
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.DefaultAntiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(HttpContext
httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.Internal.AntiforgeryMiddleware.InvokeAwaited(HttpContext
context)

How to correct this error?

based on another post, there should not be a StateHasChanged() in OnAfterRender in a component/layout/page that this form resides. removing statehaschanged call solved my problem.

this might help you identify why this is hapening
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78695819/3916499
